# Object exists as long as referenced somewhere, explicit dispose not helping?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, reference

I am bit puzzled as for why this does not throw an exception - I believe the CLR does not delete the object because there is a reference to it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> listOfA = new List<A>();

            A a = new A();

            listOfA.Add(a);

            ((IDisposable)a).Dispose();

            listOfA[0].Check(); //here I would expect and exception as the reference should point to an object that does not exist

        }
    }

    public class A : IDisposable
    {
        public A()
        {

        }
        public void Check()
        {

        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In my current project, an object might be referenced in many places but I would need to make sure that when I dispose it explicitly, those references will throw an exception. No idea how to that, though.

Comment: `IDisposable` is just an interface: when you call `Dispose` all it does is call the implementation (here does nothing). You cannot ask the CLR to destroy an object explicitly; an object will only be collected when there are no references to it discovered in the course of a routine or requested collected.

Comment: The correct way to do this is simply to set your object variable to `null` when you no longer need it.  Don't call `dispose` directly in a managed environment; that's the job of the `using` statement.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted I wonder? It is clearly worded and reveals an easy misunderstanding of the framework. Surely other folks new to .NET would benefit from it.

Comment: Code troubleshooting is off-topic here.

Comment: @Graham I did not downvote, but I did flag.

I flagged it because this belongs on stackoverflow, not Software Engineering. This is a question about debugging code...

Comment: If Check cannot do its work after the object is disposed, its up to you to throw an ObjectDisposedException.  You normally keep a field in the object indicating if disposed was already called as you **cannot** throw an exception no matter how many times Dispose is called, so the flag also helps you not try to actually dispose a second time.

Answer (score 3):

> I believe the CLR does not delete the object because there is a reference to it?

Yes, that is the case.

`disposableObject.Dispose()` in C# does not dispose the object itself, but rather gives the object the opportunity to release resources that it holds.  It would do this by, in turn, calling `Dispose()` on its members.

This is particularly important if the resources are operating system resources like handles referring to files and such.

The object could also "let go" of memory if it wanted to, by setting its reference members to null.  However, this is generally not done because (1) this does not immediately reclaim these objects even if they are no longer referenced, and (2) the GC will reclaim the objects as a group anyway.